# Preserve QStandardItem subclasses in drag and drop

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt5, qstandarditem

I have:

```
self.treeView = QTreeView()
self.treeView.setObjectName("testView")
self.treeView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

itemA = SubclassQStandardItemA(self)
itemB = SubcalssQStandardItemB(self)

self.model = QStandardItemModel()
self.treeView.setModel(self.model)

self.model.appendRow(itemA)
self.model.appendRow(itemB)
```

When I move itemB to itemA and check its class, ItemB is no longer a SubclassQStandardItemB but a QStandardItem.

How can I keep the original class of the item when I drag and drop?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for the solution ! The solution in your link work but only if I have 1 custom class. How can I work with 2 custom classes?  SubclassQStandardItemA & SubclassQStandardItemB

Comment: In that case, you will need to take a different approach - see my answer for one possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39584272/984421), you can use [setItemPrototype](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItemPrototype) to provide an item factory for a model. However, as also stated in the answer, only certain kinds of information are transferred during a drag and drop operation. For a `QStandardItem`, this means only the [item flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#flags) and [item data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#data). There is no way to preserve the specific subclass of the item if there are multiple subclasses being used. A model can have only one prototype, and that is used for all items that are created internally by Qt.

This means you should not use multiple `QStandardItem` subclasses if you need to distinguish between different item types. Instead, you should use a single subclass and reimplement [QStandardItem.type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#ItemType-enum) to distinguish between them:

```
class MyItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    TypeItemA = QtGui.QStandardItem.UserType
    TypeItemB = QtGui.QStandardItem.UserType + 1
    TypeItemC = QtGui.QStandardItem.UserType + 2

    def clone(self):
        return MyItem()

    def type(self):
        return self.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000)

    def setType(self, value):
        self.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000, value)

...

itemA = MyItem(self)
itemA.setType(MyItem.TypeItemA)
itemB = MyItem(self)
itemB.setType(MyItem.TypeItemB)
```

Comment: I tried that code, I got an error. AttributeError: type object 'QStandardItem' has no attribute 'UserData' Then I replaced UserData with UserType, that worked for some cases but I'm still puzzled... If I were to set up in __init__ self.userCustomStuff = something, and then I'd like to take that to newly droped item... do I use type/setType ? or I need data/setData? Do you know of any palce that explains it in pyqt /pyside way perhaps?

Comment: @Dariusz. I fixed the code example. As I explained in my answer, only the item-flags and item-data are transferred in a drag-drop. Anything else is completely ignored. So you must use `setData` with a custom role for custom user data (which is exactly how `type` works in my example). If you want python-style attributes, you could implement that with [@property](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: just wanted to let you know that only now (when I started doing C++ Qt) after (almost) a year I now actually understand properly what the heck you mean and I love it lol. Thanks!