# QT, Python, QTreeView, custom widget, setData - lose reference after drag and drop

Tags: python, qt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

This question is similar to the one in this this topic [Preserve QStandardItem subclasses in drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413221/preserve-qstandarditem-subclasses-in-drag-and-drop?noredirect=1#comment68098981_40413221) but with issue that I cant find a good solution for. That topic partially helps but fail on more complex task.

When I create an item in QTreeView I put that item in my array but when I use drag&Drop the item gets deleted and I no longer have access to it. I know that its because drag and drop copies the item and not moves it so I should use setData. I cant setData to be an object because even then the object gets copied and I lose reference to it.

Here is an example

```
itemsArray = self.addNewRow
def addNewRow(self)
    '''some code with more items'''
    itemHolder = QStandardItem("ProgressBarItem")
    widget = QProgressBar()
    itemHolder.setData(widget)

    inx = self.model.rowCount()
    self.model.setItem(inx, 0, itemIcon)
    self.model.setItem(inx, 1, itemName)
    self.model.setItem(inx, 2, itemHolder)
    ix = self.model.index(inx,2,QModelIndex())
    self.treeView.setIndexWidget(ix, widget)
    return [itemHolder, itemA, itemB, itemC]

#Simplified functionality
data = [xxx,xxx,xxx]
for items in itemsArray:
     items[0].data().setPercentage(data[0])
     items[1].data().setText(data[1])
     items[2].data().setChecked(data[2])
```

The code above works if I won't move the widget. The second I drag/drop I lose reference I lose updates on all my items and I get crash.

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted
```

The way I can think of of fixing this problem is to loop over entire treeview recursively over each row/child and on name match update item.... Problem is that I will be refreshing treeview every 0.5 second and have 500+ rows with 5-15 items each. Meaning... I don't think that will be very fast/efficient... if I want to loop over 5 000 items every 0.5 second...

Can some one suggest how I could solve this problem? Perhaps I can edit dropEvent so it does not copy/paste item but rather move item.... This way I would not lose my object in array

Answer (score 1):

Qt can only serialize objects that can be stored in a `QVariant`, so it's no surprise that this won't work with a `QWidget`. But even if it could serialize widgets, I still don't think it would work, because index-widgets belong to the view, not the model.

Anyway, I think you will have to keep references to the widgets separately, and only store a simple key in the model items. Then once the items are dropped, you can retrieve the widgets and reset them in the view.

Here's a working demo script:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))
        self._widgets = {}
        self._dropping = False
        self._droprange = range(0)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self._dropping = True
        super(TreeView, self).dropEvent(event)
        for row in self._droprange:
            item = self.model().item(row, 2)
            self.setIndexWidget(item.index(), self._widgets[item.data()])
            self._droprange = range(0)
        self._dropping = False

    def rowsInserted(self, parent, start, end):
        super(TreeView, self).rowsInserted(parent, start, end)
        if self._dropping:
            self._droprange = range(start, end + 1)

    def addNewRow(self, name):
        model = self.model()
        itemIcon = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
        pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(name))
        itemIcon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(pixmap))
        itemName = QtGui.QStandardItem(name.title())
        itemHolder = QtGui.QStandardItem('ProgressBarItem')
        widget = QtGui.QProgressBar()
        widget.setValue(5 * (model.rowCount() + 1))
        key = id(widget)
        self._widgets[key] = widget
        itemHolder.setData(key)
        model.appendRow([itemIcon, itemName, itemHolder])
        self.setIndexWidget(model.indexFromItem(itemHolder), widget)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.treeView = TreeView()
        for name in 'red yellow green purple blue orange'.split():
            self.treeView.addNewRow(name)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 150, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I had something similar in works with dictionary and ID, But as I learned when I drag/drop because setIndexWidget puts the object that is in array also in treeview when QT Copy/past also removed the item. Causing error too - unless I did other mistake. In any case what I'm trying to do is to after `dropEvent() super(treeView, self).dropEvent(event) self.treeView.reInitializeView()` so I would recusively loop over each widget, and re-attach a new progress bar to them. It works for 90% of issues but what it also does is duplicate the item :- (, what is the last function in drop event?

Comment: @Dariusz. It all works fine for me. I've a added a complete demo script to my answer.

Comment: it semi works, once you drag 0 item to another 0 item, the child item will have ProgressBarItem text instead of progress. What I ended up doing was to specify in progressbar a function that looks for specific place in array for data. It works when I move items and so on as it always retain the ID of location of data in array. I always call update function on dragEvent to re-attached these progress bars. On a side note if I drag by item 1-2-3(other than 0) on top of another item. The item row disappear, perhaps you know how to limit that maybe ? https://youtu.be/L6qLuC2dmhE example

Comment: @Dariusz. I assumed you were only changing the top-level order of the rows, so my example is not going to be much use as it stands. Having investigated further, the default drag and drop behaviour seems utterly bizarre and deeply uninituitive - almost to the point of being buggy. At the moment, it looks like the only way to fix things properly may be to reimplement `dropEvent` - but that would be a lot of work. I will keeping looking, though, and try to come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: @Dariusz. I have now tried drag and drop with both `QTreeView` and `QTreeWidget` and confirmed that the default behaviour is very buggy. I tried every combination of settings and could not find a single one that worked normally.