# QListWidgetItem loses superclass during drag-drop event

Tags: inheritance, python-3.5, pyqt5

I have a custom ListWidgetItem class `SubItem` which inherits from the usual QListWidgetItem. When I drag/drop the item between two ListWidgets, I lose everything which is not part of QListWidgetItem. A demonstrative example is below. Note that all items are originally listed as `SubItem` type. We can access the usual ListWidgetItem attributes like `setBackground()` and also the new attributes defined in `SubItem` like `name`. Once an item is dragged to listWidget2, it retains its background, but it no longer has access to the name attribute. Commenting out the name attribute, the `printTypes()` function confirms that the item now is a QListWidgetItem rather than a SubClass item.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class SubItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(SubItem, self).__init__(name)

        self.setBackground(QtGui.QColor('#A3B5C7'))

        self.name = name

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.listWidget1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget1.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.listWidget1.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listWidget1.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.listWidget1.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.listWidget1)

        for n in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            self.listWidget1.addItem(SubItem(n))

        self.listWidget2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget2.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.listWidget2.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listWidget2.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.listWidget2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.listWidget2)


        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Types')
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.printTypes)
        self.show()


    def printTypes(self):
        count = self.listWidget1.count()
        for i in range(count):
            item = self.listWidget1.item(i)
            print('Widget1: ', item.name, item)

        count = self.listWidget2.count()
        for i in range(count):
            item = self.listWidget2.item(i)
            print('Widget2: ', item.name, item)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
m = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Do I need to overload the `dropEvent()` in some way? How can I ensure that my entire class is passed to the new ListWidget?

Comment: There's no way to do that. The best you can do is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39584272/984421) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40425316/984421) (the model/items of a list-widget work the same way).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to pass the necessary information in the `setData` function. Should we close as duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop a custom QStandardItem into a QListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584001/how-to-drop-a-custom-qstandarditem-into-a-qlistview)