# PySide - QListView creating new item during drag and drop rather than passing original

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am writing a PySide application with a `QListView`. This `QListView` allows drag and drop events to change the order of the items it displays.

The `QListView` uses a `QStandardItemModel`, and the `QStandardItemModel` contains `QStanardItem` objects. I have given these `QStandardItem` objects custom instance attributes, as follows:

```
def createShotItem(self, path, display_name, name):
    item = CustomItem(display_name)
    item.setCheckable(True)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    item.path = path
    item.name = name
    item.fields = {}  # Used to store setting fields

    return item
```

Below is the `CustomItem` class.

```
class CustomItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.shot_path = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.fields = {}
        super(CustomItem, self).__init__(text)
```

Previously, I was simply adding the attributes directly to a `QStandardItem`, without using a sub-class. There was no difference.

The sub-classed `QListView` and `QStandardItemModel` classes are as follows:

```
class DragDropListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DragDropListView, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
                event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(DragDropListView, self).dragEnterEvent(event)
class DragDropItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DragDropItemModel, self).__init__()

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled \
                   | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled \
               | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
```

When I later attempt to access one of these attributes on an item who has been moved in the list, I get an error as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QStandardItem' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

As you can see, my `CustomItem`, which extends `QStandardItem`, has been replaced by a `QStandardItem` that does not contain any of my custom attributes.

I believe that this is because, when a re-order occurs, due to a drag-and-drop event, PySide creates a new `QStandardItem` at the desired index, containing the same `text` attribute, and other PySide attributes, but discarding my custom attributes.

Note that accessing these custom attributes works fine on all unmoved items. Also, appending or inserting a `CustomItem` using `model.appendRow(item)` or `model.insertRow(index, item)` works fine, so the issue is not with those methods.

How can I maintain these custom attributes throughout move events? Do I need to alter the behavior of the move event, and if so, how?

Comment: See also [this closely related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40425316/984421).