# QStandardItem does not clone correctly when the items are moved

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

As indicated in the following code, when you drag-drop an item (subclassed from `QStandardItem` with a `clone()` method) you get a `QStandardItem` and not a subclass.   Furthermore - data stored in the class or as part of the setData is lost.   I suspect this is because of the inability to 'serialize' the data.  But I am clueless how to 'save' the data - or the meta.  How can I preserve the `QObject`?  The following code works fine, but once you move a branch node, all the nodes in the branch and the branch become `QStandardItem`'s and not `myItem` and lose the data (if they had any).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov  4 09:10:16 2019

Test of Tree view with subclassed QStandardItem and Drag and Drop
enabled.  When you move a parent the parent looses the subclass and thus
the meta - however, it also looses the data:  This is likely because
the data cannot be serialized.  How to fix?

@author: tcarnaha
"""
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class myData():
    def __init__(self, title):
        self._title = title
        self._stuff = dict()
        self._obj = QtCore.QObject()

    @property
    def obj(self):
        return self._obj

    @obj.setter
    def obj(self, value):
        self._obj = value

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    def title(self, value):
        self._title = value


class myItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self._meta = None

    @property
    def meta(self):
        return self._meta

    @meta.setter
    def meta(self, value):
        self._meta = value

    def clone(self):
        print "My cloning"
        old_data = self.data()
        print "Old data [{}]".format(old_data)
        old_meta = self.meta
        obj = myItem()
        obj.setData(old_data)
        print "New data [{}]".format(obj.data())
        obj.meta = old_meta
        print "Clone is a ", obj.__class__
        return obj

class mainWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setItemPrototype(myItem())
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.view.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.list_click)
        self.view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.view.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.view.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.view.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.view.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        dataA = myData('A thing')
        parentA = myItem()
        parentA.setText('A')
        parentA.setDragEnabled(True)
        parentA.setDropEnabled(True)
        parentA.setData(dataA)
        parentA.meta = QtCore.QObject()
        childa = myItem()
        childa.setText('a')
        childb = myItem()
        childb.setText('b')
        childc = myItem()
        childc.setText('c')
        parentA.appendRows([childa, childb, childc])
        dataB = myData('B thing')
        parentB = myItem()
        parentB.setText('B')
        parentB.setDragEnabled(True)
        parentB.setDropEnabled(True)
        parentB.setData(dataB)
        parentB.meta = QtCore.QObject()
        childd = myItem()
        childd.setText('d')
        childe = myItem()
        childe.setText('e')
        childf = myItem()
        childf.setText('f')
        parentB.appendRows([childd, childe, childf])
        self.model.appendRow(parentA)
        self.model.appendRow(parentB)

        classAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Class', self)
        classAct.triggered.connect(self.classIs)
        dataAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Data', self)
        dataAct.triggered.connect(self.dataIs)
        metaAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Meta', self)
        metaAct.triggered.connect(self.metaIs)
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Item info")
        self.menu.addAction(classAct)
        self.menu.addAction(dataAct)
        self.menu.addAction(metaAct)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def list_click(self, position):
        self.menu.popup(self.view.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))

    def classIs(self):
        selected_indexes = self.view.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            print "Item {} Class {} ".format(item.text(), item.__class__())

    def dataIs(self):
        selected_indexes = self.view.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            try:
                print "Item {} data {} Object {}".format(item.text(),
                                                         item.data().title,
                                                         item.data().obj)
            except Exception as exc:
                print "Data exception ", exc

    def metaIs(self):
        selected_indexes = self.view.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            try:
                print "Item {} meta {} ".format(item.text(), item.meta)
            except Exception as exc:
                print "Meta exception ", exc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainWidget()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I think you mean obj = myItem() instead of the obj = super().  Fine - I understand that - however, regardless the 'data' and the 'meta' are lost.  How to avoid that?

Comment: Okay well once you have made a copy of the correct Object then it is just a matter of copying the data/meta-data from the prime object to the new object -- which you would of course have to do manually -- but should be part of your classes -- copy functionality  Note make sure when you are doing it you are copying apples to apples sometimes you have to extract the data in order to use the setData function

Comment: In the attached code is an attempt to do exactly that - but it does not work.   Saving the data (or the meta data) in the clone method does not work:  The following error occurs on the .data():  Data exception  unable to convert a QVariant back to a Python object

Comment: Look at your QStandardItem object documentation because no you cannot do it the way you are doing it -- you get data using `obj.data()` but you set the data using `obj.setData(value[, role=Qt.UserRole + 1])` which I believe is how you set the MetaData as well - not 100% sure without digging more deeply into it -- which you should be able to do now

Comment: Neither of those work.  I try to get the data with old_data = self.data() (It is implied and does not change the behavior if I use role=Qt.UserRole+1)  The point is before clone is called the data (or meta) is lost.   Trying to save the meta in a similar fashion fails.

Comment: Okay, but I think this is a more general issue with QStandardItem (or the model/view?) wherein cloning an object is not able to 'serialize' the data within - So for any complex (QObject ...) data structure you will not be able to use the Model/View structure to save data (if you wish to support Drag and Drop operations)

Comment: Could be but then again might not be -- I would need to play with it and cross-reference the documentation and figure out how it ought to be done properly before I would make that statement -- to me it still seems pretty straightforward from my understanding of the QStandardItem object and PyQt Model methodology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here related to how objects get serialized by Qt and also by PyQt. Firstly, when cloning a `QStandardItem`, only the flags and data get copied - everything else is ignored (including dynamic python attributes). Secondly, there is no way to directly copy a `QObject`. This is because it cannot be cast to a `QVariant` (which Qt uses for serialization) and it cannot be pickled (which PyQt uses for serialization).

To solve the second problem, we need to keep separate references to all the `QObject` instances, and then use indirect keys to access them again later. There are probably many different way to achieve this, but here's a very simple approach that illustrates the basic idea:

```
objects = {}

class MyObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setProperty('key', max(objects.keys() or [0]) + 1)
        objects[self.property('key')] = self
```

So this automatically adds each instance to a global cache and gives it a unique lookup key so that it can be easily found later on. With this in place, the `myData` class now needs to be adapted to use the `MyObject` class so that [pickling is handled correctly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__):

```
class myData():
    def __init__(self, title):
        self._title = title
        self._stuff = dict()
        self._obj = MyObject()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self._obj = objects.get(state['obj'])
        self._stuff = state['stuff']
        self._title = state['title']

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            'obj': self._obj and self._obj.property('key'),
            'title': self._title,
            'stuff': self._stuff,
            }
```

Solving the first problem is much simpler: we just need to make sure any dynamic python properties store their underlying values in the item's data using custom data-roles. In this particular case, the value must be the key of the item's `MyObject` instance, so that it can be retrieved after a drag and drop operation:

```
class myItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    MetaRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000

    @property
    def meta(self):
        return objects.get(self.data(myItem.MetaRole))

    @meta.setter
    def meta(self, value):
        self.setData(value.property('key'), myItem.MetaRole)

    def clone(self):
        print "My cloning"
        obj = myItem(self)
        print "Clone is a ", obj.__class__
        return obj
```

Below is a working version of your original script that implements all the above. But please bear in mind that you will almost certainly need to adapt this to work properly with your real code. This is just a working proof-of-concept that shows how to deal with the two issues outlined above.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

objects = {}

class MyObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setProperty('key', max(objects.keys() or [0]) + 1)
        objects[self.property('key')] = self

class myData():
    def __init__(self, title):
        self._title = title
        self._stuff = dict()
        self._obj = MyObject()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self._obj = objects.get(state['obj'])
        self._stuff = state['stuff']
        self._title = state['title']

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            'obj': self._obj.property('key'),
            'title': self._title,
            'stuff': self._stuff,
            }

    @property
    def obj(self):
        return self._obj

    @obj.setter
    def obj(self, value):
        self._obj = value

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    def title(self, value):
        self._title = value

class myItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    MetaRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000

    @property
    def meta(self):
        return objects.get(self.data(myItem.MetaRole))

    @meta.setter
    def meta(self, value):
        self.setData(value.property('key'), myItem.MetaRole)

    def clone(self):
        print "My cloning"
        obj = myItem(self)
        print "Clone is a ", obj.__class__
        return obj

class mainWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setItemPrototype(myItem())
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.view.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.list_click)
        self.view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.view.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.view.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.view.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.view.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        dataA = myData('A thing')
        parentA = myItem()
        parentA.setText('A')
        parentA.setDragEnabled(True)
        parentA.setDropEnabled(True)
        parentA.setData(dataA)
        parentA.meta = MyObject()
        childa = myItem()
        childa.setText('a')
        childb = myItem()
        childb.setText('b')
        childc = myItem()
        childc.setText('c')
        parentA.appendRows([childa, childb, childc])
        dataB = myData('B thing')
        parentB = myItem()
        parentB.setText('B')
        parentB.setDragEnabled(True)
        parentB.setDropEnabled(True)
        parentB.setData(dataB)
        parentB.meta = MyObject()
        childd = myItem()
        childd.setText('d')
        childe = myItem()
        childe.setText('e')
        childf = myItem()
        childf.setText('f')
        parentB.appendRows([childd, childe, childf])
        self.model.appendRow(parentA)
        self.model.appendRow(parentB)

        classAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Class', self)
        classAct.triggered.connect(self.classIs)
        dataAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Data', self)
        dataAct.triggered.connect(self.dataIs)
        metaAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Meta', self)
        metaAct.triggered.connect(self.metaIs)
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Item info")
        self.menu.addAction(classAct)
        self.menu.addAction(dataAct)
        self.menu.addAction(metaAct)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def list_click(self, position):
        self.menu.popup(self.view.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))

    def classIs(self):
        selected_indexes = self.view.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            print "Item {} Class {} ".format(item.text(), item.__class__())

    def dataIs(self):
        selected_indexes = self.view.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            try:
                print "Item {} data {} Object {}".format(item.text(),
                                                         item.data().title,
                                                         item.data().obj)
            except Exception as exc:
                print "Data exception ", exc

    def metaIs(self):
        selected_indexes = self.view.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            try:
                print "Item {} meta {} ".format(item.text(), item.meta)
            except Exception as exc:
                print "Meta exception ", exc


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainWidget()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Interesting indeed.  Using a global data structure (a dict) to store the references to the 'real' data.  I am sure this work in simple example provide - I have no doubt.   Whether or not it works in my larger application is going to prove entertaining.   But I think this question and answer may cover a hidden 'feature' of using QStandardItem.

Comment: @TimCarnahan No, `QStandardItem` works exactly as expected. The only difficulty is with copying `QObject`, and that is not a hidden feature - it is [well-documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator). The real problem is in the design of your application, which is trying to do something which Qt explicitly does not support.

Answer (score 0):

You are not cloning your class, but a normal `QStandardItem`:

```
obj = super(myItem, self).clone()
```

This actually means "call the `clone()` method of the *base* class".
When subclassing from a single class, `super()` acts exactly like calling the class method with the subclass instance as first argument, so in this case it is exacly as doing this:

```
obj = QtGui.QStandardItem.clone(self)
```

The most common advantage of `super()` is simplicity and maintainance (if you change the base class you're going to inherit you only have to do it in the sub class declaration); other than that, its most important benefit comes from multiple inheritance, which is when you are inheriting from *more than one* base class, but since that's a rare situation in PyQt, that's not the case; also, multi-inheritance is not possible with more than one Qt class.

As specified in the [`setItemPrototype()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItemPrototype) (emphasis mine):

> To provide your own prototype, subclass QStandardItem, reimplement
>   QStandardItem::clone() and set the prototype to be an **instance of your
>   custom class**.

What `clone()` actually [does](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/13e0a36626bd75e631dd9536e795a494432b1945/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp#L2024), indeed, is to use the [`QStandardItem(other)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#QStandardItem-4) constructor, which creates a *copy* of the *other* item.

So, you can get your correct clone just by doing this:

```
def clone(self):
    obj = myItem(self)
    obj.setData(self.data())
    obj.meta = self.meta
    return obj
```

Comment: Sorry  - No ... That solution does not work - before you get to .setData and meta = self.meta the data is lost - per the discussion with Dennis Jensen above - I acknowledge your observation on the obj = myItem() but the underlying issue is that when you drag/drop an item in a tree the data (meta or data() ) is LOST.   How do you recover it (or save it appropriately)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The reason is that QStandardItemModel uses the *`itemPrototype`* as the source for the clone, not the item itself. So I'm afraid that the only way to correctly update the data is to reimplement the dropEvent of the view. I cannot test nor update my answer right now, but I'll do it tonight if you're not able to get it before then.

Comment: @TimCarnahan See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39584272/984421) on this topic. When cloning, only the item data and flags are copied - everything else is ignored. Also, Qt does not allow copying `QObject`, so there is no direct way to serialise an instance during a drag-drop operation. In addition, PyQt copies your `myData` instance by using `pickle` - but of course`QObject` is not pickleable, so that will fail as well. One way to work around this would be to keep the `QObject` instances in a `dict`, and then clone the keys instead.

Comment: @musicamante That is not the reason. The problem is that Qt must serialise the data using `QVariant`, so that limits what can be copied.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I believe you are correct and how to do that escapes me.   I have understood that pickle (or serialization) does not work with QObject (thus when I want to 'save' my session I must remove QObject - in order to generate a cPickle file) - however, for within the program in order to support the drag/drop actions I am lost.   (internal serializing is something that eludes me and even if I knew HOW I do not know WHERE).  Your answer above was exactly where I started to look - but then the QObject problem arose and thus here I am.

Comment: @TimCarnahan It's not too difficult to work around, but are you ***absolutely sure*** you have to use `QObject` in this way? Things would become a lot simpler if you could eliminate the `QObject`.

Comment: @ekhumoro - Honestly I understand that in this example QObject makes little sense.  However, in my large project it is much more difficult to eliminate the sub-classed QObject things myItem is supporting.  I also acknowledge that the documentation supports the idea that because of serialization there is an issue storing data.  I did use your  answer to start my solution - but am still confused how to support the QObject type data.

Comment: @TimCarnahan I have added an answer that provides a working solution.

Comment: @ekhumoro what I meant is that, in the case of itemPrototype, `clone()` is not meant to "copy the content" of the dropped item, as it's used to clone the prototype, and it's up to the item view to set the cloned item data according to the drag/drop action.